# How to select row before and after row with specific text in Excel?

Tags: excel

My raw data looks something like this;

```
std1
std1
deviant
std2
std1
std2
std2
deviant
```

The "deviants" are presented randomly and thus do not occur every nth row...

I wish to select 1 row before and 1 row after each "deviant" row so I can copy it in another spread sheet.

Comment: You are going to have to be a lot more clear about what you are asking. What are you trying to do, what have you tried, and what results did you get. You should show your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry Bruce I have never used this before!

Comment: I am wanting to compare performance on trials before and after "deviant" trials, I have so far tried to use the sumproduct and isnumber formukas with no luck so far...

Comment: I thought of maybe making the deviant rows blank and then trying to come up with a formula that selects one row before and after every blank row?

Answer (score 0):

See code below.

We loop through each row in the column (I have assumed your data is in column A) and when the given value is found, we add the following and prior rows to our selection array. When the loop is complete, we select the rows in the array

```
Public Sub DeviantSelect()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Nothing
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 1) = "deviant" Then
            If myRange Is Nothing Then
                Set myRange = Union(Range(i - 1 & ":" & i - 1), Range(i + 1 & ":" & i + 1))
            Else
                Set myRange = Union(myRange, Range(i - 1 & ":" & i - 1), Range(i + 1 & ":" & i + 1))
            End If
            myRange.Select
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code copies the cells before and after deviant to another sheet.

```
    Sub check()
Sheet1.Activate
Range("A1").Select

 LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow
Sheet1.Activate

If Range("A" & i).Value = "deviant" Then
Range("A" & i - 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheet2.Activate
 LastRow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
 If LastRow2 = 1 Then
 Range("A" & LastRow2).Activate
 Else
 Range("A" & LastRow2 + 1).Activate
 End If
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheet1.Activate
Range("A" & i + 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheet2.Activate
 LastRow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
 Range("A" & LastRow2 + 1).Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste

End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for this, I was almost close to resorting to manually selecting the cells!!